# How to use ContentPlaceHolderId CMS (Umbraco)

Tags: html, content-management-system, umbraco, contentplaceholder

I have a simple master template with HTML tags and I want to put a footer and header in it. For some reason it doesn't display both the header and footer at the same time. Am I using ContentPlaceHolderId wrong? Should they not be all templates?

MASTER template

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="header" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder Id="footer" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</body></html>
</asp:Content>
```

Master (child node: header) template:

```
<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="header" runat="server">TEST</asp:content>
```

Master (child node: footer) template:

```
<asp:content ContentPlaceHolderId="footer" runat="server">TEST</asp:content>
```

I have 3 doc types (master, header, footer) with the id of header and footer.

Comment: nobody???      no one knows???

Comment: If an answer is acceptable please mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing. Create a template and inside

< asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolderDefault" runat="server">

< div>header< /div>

< div>body< /div>

< div>footer< /div>

< /asp:Content>

add your html code which will contain the header,body and footer.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've set up your header/footer templates as children of your "site master" template, which means you can only pick *either* header or footer template. Also sounds like you've set them up as sub-nodes of your homepage... I'm not sure why you'd do this.

You should be putting header and footer content inside your main template. If you want it to be content-editable (which it sounds like you might), set up a document type with the rich text fields "bodyHeader" and "bodyFooter", then use `<umbraco:Item Field="bodyHeader" runat="server" />` to insert the content into your template.

HTH,

Benjamin